# What is wrong with me redirect regular expression?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 redirects and they both redirect internally.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^[^.]+\.[^.]$
 RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
 RewriteRule   ^(.*)\/(.*) /var/www/$1/www.$1/$2 #THIS line is not working

 RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
 RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.(.*/)(.*) /var/www/$2$1.$2$3
```

i cant get the first one working.
it should be doing:
url: example.org/the/uri/the/user/used
rewriterule should redirect him to: /var/www/example.org/www.example.org/the/uri/the/user/used

So my question is: What is the regular expression that i'm looking for?

EDIT:

This is my engine now :)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin *@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}                ^[^.]+\..[^.]+$
        RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
        RewriteRule   ^([^\/]*)(.*)$            /var/www/$1/www.$1/$2 [L]

        RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
        RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.(.*/)(.*) /var/www/$2$1.$2$3 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

it redirect example.org internally to /var/www/example.org/www.example.org
and for the second part. it redirects foo.example.org to /var/www/example.org/foo.example.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
^[^:]*:\s*([^\/]*)(.*)$
```

Without uri section, your regex would be,

```
^([^\/]*)(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dI0jR6)

Explanation:

```
url: example.org/the/uri/the/user/used
```

In the above example, the string after `:` and the next `/` are captured into group1. And the remaining part are captured into group2. By giving `/var/www/$1/www.$1$2` in the substitution part may give you the desired result.(Marker for denoting captured group may vary upon languages, i used `$` for representing captured group).

Comment: without the url:. i try'd to mody it and the tester you linked me also said it works fine. but now it wont work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}  (?:www\.)?(.*)
RewriteRule   (.*)          /var/www/%1/www.%1/$1
```

I tested it here, and it works as expected: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: It's almost working! the rewriteCondition should deny the rewrite if it starts with www. Also strange enough it didnt work. when i try'd mysite.com it gave an 404 error.